# Как обрабатывать 2 запроса ajax в одном php файле?

Tags: php, ajax

Можно ли сделать обработку двух `ajax` запросов на одном файле обработчике? Сейчас для селектов я использую два файла, которые одинаковые по коду.

До этого, когда я отправлял запросы (В какой кабинет) на один php-файл, второй селект не отображал вообще кабинеты. То есть тегов `option` не было.

Есть форма, которая подставляет значение селекта в зависимости от выбранного здания

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="form">

        <p>Откуда</p>
        <select name="building_from" id="building_id_from">
            <?php 
                foreach($buildings as $item) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $item[0]; ?>"><?php echo $item[1]; ?></option>
            <?php
                };
            ?>
        </select>

        <p>От какого кабинета</p>
        <select name="cabinet_from" id="cabinet_id_from">
            <?php 
                $offices = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `building_offices` WHERE `building_ID` = 1" );
                while($office_from = mysqli_fetch_assoc($offices)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $office_from['number']; ?>">к.<?php echo $office_from['number']; ?> | <?php echo $office_from['name']; ?> </option>
            <?php
                };
            ?>
        </select>

        <p>Куда</p>
        <select name="building_to" id="building_id_to">
            <?php 
                foreach($buildings as $item) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $item[0]; ?>"><?php echo $item[1]; ?></option>
            <?php
                };
            ?>
        </select>

        <p>В какой кабинет</p>
        <select name="cabinet_to" id="cabinet_id_to">
            <?php
                $offices = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `building_offices` WHERE `building_ID` = 1" );
                while($office_to = mysqli_fetch_assoc($offices)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $office_to['number']; ?>">к.<?php echo $office_to['number']; ?> | <?php echo $office_to['name']; ?> </option>
            <?php 
                };
            ?>
        </select>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Построить маршрут</button>

    </form>
```

Селекты с выбором кабинетов обрабатываются такими `ajax`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#building_id_from" ).change(function() {
                var value1 = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./navigation/fetch_from.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {request: value1},
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#cabinet_id_from").html("<span>Загрузка</span>");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#cabinet_id_from").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#building_id_to" ).change(function() {
                var value2 = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./navigation/fetch_to.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {request: value2},
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#cabinet_id_to").html("<span>Загрузка</span>");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#cabinet_id_to").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Обработчики запросов выглядят одинаково (файлы `fetch_to.php` и `fetch_from.php`):

```
<?php
    require_once '../config/connect.php';
    if(isset($_POST['request'])) {
        $request = $_POST['request'];
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `building_offices` WHERE `building_ID` = '$request'");
        while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $item['number']; ?>">к.<?php echo $item['number']; ?> | <?php echo $item['name']; ?> </option>
<?php
        }
    } 
?>
```

**UPD**

Я либо был уставшим, либо кэш не сбрасывался должным образом. Действительно селекты обрабатываются, если в `ajax` запросах указывать путь на один файл обработчик.

Comment: Можно конечно же. Не понятно в чем проблема.

Comment: У Вас в запросе есть потенциальная уязвимость для SQL инъекции.

Comment: Если в целом это нормально, что на два файла идет обработка одинакового кода, то ладно. А о какой уязвимости вы говорите?

Comment: И все же интересно, как в итоге обрабатывать в одном файле вместо двух? Пока не могу спрогнозировать где и зачем это понадобиться, но как минимум для чистоты. Что бы не плодить дубли одинакового кода

Comment: Ну я же Вам написал, что можете обрабатывать при помощи одного обработчика, **я не понимаю почему Вы этого не можете сделать и в чем возникла конкретная проблема**. Про SQL-инъекции можете почитать здесь: [SQL-инъекции для самых маленьких](https://habr.com/ru/articles/725134/) либо где угодно на просторах интернета.

Comment: Если я отправлю на один файл, второй селект с выборами кабинетов <select name="cabinet_to" id="cabinet_id_to"> будет пуст. Я и спрашиваю, как это сделать. Спасибо, что отвечаете "можно" - проблему безусловно решает.

Comment: Эммм, ну наверное смотрите что Вы отправляете. Я категорически не понимаю, каким образом отправка запроса к двум разным файлам/обработчикам внутри которых одинаковая логика, может решать проблему того что какие-то данные Вам не возвращает с бекенда, если Вы это же делаете с одним файлом. Бекенд логика ведь в них одинакова, разве нет? Потому что изначально нет разницы и каких-то строгих требований, что это обязательно должны быть разные файлы, можете в одном файле сколько угодно много различных AJAX запросов обрабатывать, если Вам это будет удобно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я либо был уставшим, либо кэш не сбрасывался должным образом. Действительно селекты обрабатываются, если в `ajax` запросах указывать путь на один файл обработчик.

В данном случае, мой вопрос более не актуален, что-бы работало в одном файле, в `ajax` запросах нужно указать путь на единственный файл.

Итого `ajax` запросы будут следующими (`url` одинаковый)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#building_id_from" ).change(function() {
                var value1 = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./navigation/fetch.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {request: value1},
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#cabinet_id_from").html("<span>Загрузка</span>");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#cabinet_id_from").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#building_id_to" ).change(function() {
                var value2 = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./navigation/fetch.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {request: value2},
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#cabinet_id_to").html("<span>Загрузка</span>");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#cabinet_id_to").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Крайний раз я был удивлен почему селект пуст, когда логика верная и по идее должно сработать. Сегодня еще раз на свежую голову посмотрел, сработало.